# update nested_attributes_for errors with uniqueness constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm working on build a user model in rails and this user model will have an associated email address model. The email address model has a uniqueness constraint on the email. Right now I have it set up so that the user accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_address. This works great on create but on update I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
"index_email_addresses_on_email"
```

I can recreate this bug by doing this in the rails console:

```
u = User.create(:name => "foo", :new_password => "Passw0rd",
        :email_address_attributes => {:email => "foo@bar.com"})
u.update({:name => "new name",
        :email_address_attributes => {:email => "foo@bar.com"}})
```

How do I get it to update the name while not caring about the email_address. Which hasn't changed?

Some other notes and code:

I do index my email_address on email and I'm using rails 4.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :email_address

  validates :email_address, :presence => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_address
end

class EmailAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :email, :with => RFC822::EmailAddress
  validates :email, :presence => true
  has_one :user
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update your `email_address_attributes` in this way, you're actually adding a new `email_address` object for your `user`. You need to pass the email address's id as an attribute, i.e.:

```
u.update({:name => "new name",
    :email_address_attributes => {:id => u.email_address.id, :email => "foo@bar.com"}})
```

Or alternatively, you can update the user's email address in a different update statement

```
u.update({:name => "new name"})
u.email_address.update({:email => "foo@bar.com"})
```

As for your controller, all you need to do is add the email addresses's `:id` field as a permitted parameter.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, email_address_attributes: [:id, :email])
end
```

There is more information about Strong Parameters in the [Strong Parameters Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). Check out the [More Example section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples) for a setup similar to yours.

Comment: This worked. The main thing was adding the :id to email_address_attributes. I had :email but not :id. Thanks.

Comment: Still a good answer in 2020! In Rails 6 without the nested attribute's ID, the nested attribute is destroyed and recreated. With the ID it is updated which was the desired behavior for my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to validate the e-mail address except on create, you can add that to the validation:

`validates :email_address, presence: true, on: :create`

Answer (score 1):

Use ":update_only" option in "accepts_nested_attributes_for" like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_address, :update_only => true
```

This way active record will update the child record if it already exists, instead of creating a new one. This should take care of the unique constraint.